# How to convert Hash to string Hash?

Tags: ruby

Here i have the use case where hash to convert to string hash.

```
hash = {"make" => "tata", "year" => "2006"}
p hash.to_s
```

output:

```
"{\"make\"=>\"tata\", \"year\"=>\"2006\"}"
```

Expected Output should be in string hash and class should be string:

```
"{"make"=>"tata", "year"=>"2006"}"
```

Comment: You may be confusing the inspection of a string with printing the string. Do a `puts` on the current output. `inspect` shows escaped characters.

Comment: Actually i know the difference that i have to use puts but  the thing is here when i convert  to_s string and zipping the the two arrays  values i has to get for key  `"{"make"=>"tata", "year"=>"2006"}"` but i m getting this `"{\"make\"=>\"tata\", \"year\"=>\"2006\"}"`

Comment: @Bharath: you missed the first part of Dave's comment.

Comment: I don't understand. `a_hash.to_s` creates a string the way you say you want it. Are you saying you want to explicitly create a string that *also* includes quotes around the *entire* string? Why?

Comment: Yeah explicitly creating a string that also includes quotes around the entire hash

Comment: @Bharath: no, that's not what you want (indicated by the fact that you accepted Sumak's answer, which does not do that). Again, you're confusing string's debug representation with the actual content of the string.

Comment: @Bharath So... `s = "\"#{hash.to_s}\""` then. But I'd bet it's not what you actually want. I believe you are confusing two representations of the same thing.

Comment: @Bharath The accepted answer duplicates `Hash#to_s` but uses single-quotes instead of double-quotes. You are still confusing the output of `inspect` (which is what `p` uses) with the string contents. I don't know how else to explain it to you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As @Sergio Tulentsev said, using `p` or `inspect` is the cleaner & simpler solution.

```rb
hash = {"make" => "tata", "year" => "2006"}
p hash
# => {"make"=>"tata", "year"=>"2006"}
puts hash.inspect
# => {"make"=>"tata", "year"=>"2006"}
```

If you want to reinvent the wheel, see below

---

If you don't mind having single quotes instead of double quotes:

```rb
hash = {"make" => "tata", "year" => "2006"}

def hash_to_string(hash)
  inner_string = hash.map do |key, value|
    "'#{key}' => '#{value}'"
  end.join(', ')

  '{' + inner_string + '}'
end 

# If you prefer overwriting Hash#to_s method
class Hash
  def to_s
    inner_string = self.map do |key, value|
      "'#{key}' => '#{value}'"
    end.join(', ')

   '{' + inner_string + '}'
  end
end

puts hash_to_string hash
# => {'make' => 'tata', 'year' => '2006'}
puts hash.to_s
# => {'make' => 'tata', 'year' => '2006'}
p hash_to_string hash
# => "{'make' => 'tata', 'year' => '2006'}"
p hash.to_s
# => "{'make' => 'tata', 'year' => '2006'}"
```

Though when you use `puts`, `"` are escaped because the String itself is surrounded by double quotes. Ruby uses double quotes to represent strings

Comment: `Hash#to_s` does that already (only with double quotes)

Comment: It's the reason why OP asked this question. Apparently he does not want escaped double quotes. My suggestion prints the hash without backslashes, so it may satisfy OP question. I'm aware it's about string representation

Comment: Thanks so much for both the answers its resolved my use cases.

Comment: @Bharath Don't override `Hash#to_s`. But your question is still non-sensical; `Hash#to_s` does precisely what you're asking for.

Comment: @Sumak The "string itself" is not surrounded by double-quotes; strings are *created* using quotes, they do not *include* those quotes. When you use `puts` you do *not* see `\"` because they're printed. The representation of a double-quote *when inspected* is `\"`, when it's simply printed, it's `"`; *when inspected* Ruby displays surrounding quotes.

Comment: @DaveNewton I get you point, and thanks for insisting (it makes it clearer for everyone reading this). Can we say that there's a difference about how string are represented (using the method I wrote & default Hash#to_s) ? If, for example, we want to display "good looking" Hash (maybe someone doesn't like escaped characters)

Comment: @Sumak: if someone doesn't like escaped characters, they shouldn't print with `p` or `inspect`. Reimplementing this basic piece of functionality is not the solution.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You're totally right, I'll add it at the top of my answer. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @Sumak No. That is the same mistake the OP is making. Characters that need escaping are only *shown* as escaped when the string is *inspected*. Inspecting a string is explicitly different than *printing* a string. "puts" prints. "p" inspects.

Comment: @Sumak Also, that's not what Sergio said. Using "p" on its own does not do what the OP wants: OP wants a string representation of a hash, which is what "to_s" returns. If you *inspect* that string you'll see the escaped chars. If you *print* that string you won't. Inspecting the *hash* is a different thing altogether.

Comment: Yeah, what I've actually said was exactly the opposite :)

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented, you actually get what you look for just using `to_s`. What you see when you `p` the string is the *inspect* representation if the string itself, one that when put in a code file will be your original string.

If you want an additional proof that the string is what you want, just eval the resulting string:

```rb
string = {"a" => "b"}.to_s
=>  "{\"a\"=>\"b\"}"

rebuilt = eval string
=> {"a" => "b"}

rebuilt.class
=> Hash

rebuilt.keys[0].class
=> String

rebuilt.values[0].class
=> String
```